# How to configure automatic commit rejection in SVN if code style violations are found?

Tags: svn

I have seen something like in the subject on one project but I don't know how to do that and what a the correct keywords to google it.

Is it done by means of SVN of by some 3rd-party tool? Is it possible to specify a set of files to be verified (i.e. not the whole project but only some its 'clean' part)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN - pre-commit hook to check code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407909/svn-pre-commit-hook-to-check-code-formatting)

Comment: What you are looking for is a "pre-commit hook"; see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks . A similar question has been asked before, so your question may be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it with SVN pre-commit hooks. Get a build server instead.

Write a build script that calls some 3rd-party tool to validate your coding style (what tools you can use to do that depends of the programming language you're using.. for C# it's something like StyleCop).

Google "continuous integration" for plenty of profit.

Comment: [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) (unaffiliated) has nice hooks for doing this type of work.

Comment: @stmax: just to provide you with a whole picture: currently I'm comparing CI code validation against SVN pre-commit validation. I also tend to go with CI-based solution.

Comment: I see.. I guess the pre-commit hook approach tends to turn into a "manually check what's changed with svnlook and some ugly regexes"-hack where you have to script pretty much everything yourself.. figure out the changes with svnlook + some regex and maybe some python suggar, then checkout and finally invoke the code style validation tool. Problem with invoking the code style validation tool might be that it's not available for the system your SVN server runs on (our SVN runs on Linux, while we need .NET build tools). CI would be much more flexible and easier to implement.